# unrelated business taxable income

Tags: united-states, taxes

My wife and I are partners in a real estate mortgage business that divides the interest (minus office expenses) proportionally among all the partners.  Generates IRS form 1065 K-1 and K-3 every year.  Pages and pages explaining in detail (with citations to IRS docs) the reason for everything, but boiling down to all being ordinary income for Schedule E.

**Except** for about a quarter of a percent being called "unrelated business taxable income" for which the only explanation is "please ask your tax consultant."  Without a citation to anything, how can "my tax consultant" (which happens to be me!) figure out what to do with it?  Web search for the phrase turns up nothing.  Re-ordering it to "unrelated taxable business income" only gets things about stock market risks, which clearly are irrelevant to mortgage interest.

In our tax bracket, the impact of an error is less than five dollars—plus any penalties should IRS not like what we do or don't do with it!

**What *should* we do with this?**

Comment: Are you contributing anything to the business or is it completely passive?

Comment: Passive.  The "minus office expanses" includes paying the folks that do all the work.  Our cut is seven to eight percent APR on what we put in.

Comment: I don't see this phrase appearing anywhere neither on K1 nor on K3, where is it?

Comment: It's typed on my second page as an "explanation" for block 20 code 'V'

Comment: That's "unrelated", not "unregulated"

Comment: @littleadv, correct; I will edit.  Maybe that's why my web search failed to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that it is shown on your 1065 K1 line 20 with Code V. See the [instructions here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1065#en_US_2023_publink1000100880) ([PDF version](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1065sk1.pdf) is more detailed, see page 28). This information is intended for tax-exempt partners and includes unrelated business income which would be taxable to tax-exempt entities. See the [IRC Sec 512](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/512). This likely refers to income not directly related to the mortgage business (interest income on bank balances, for example).

Since you're an individual non-exempt taxpayer, this is irrelevant to you and you can ignore it.