# How to handle an account that lost value after inheritance? (USA)

Tags: united-states, mortgage, investment-strategies

The exact amounts aren't important, so I'll just invent some for the example.

My wife’s mother put $50,000 into a mortgage sharing fund¹ from which she received a proportional share of the interest.  Some time later, the loan went into default.  She died in 2022 and my wife inherited her share of the remaining principal, say $10,000.  No payments and therefore no interest in 2022.

In 2023, there were finally some payments and we² received $200 interest.  In 2024, the default was settled at a loss and our share of the payoff was $5000.

We have neither 1099 nor K-1, and requesting one didn't help.  Based on the K-1 we did received from the similar¹ investment, I suspect we could declare the $200 interest on Schedule E the same way we did the others, and next year (2024 return) put the $5000 loss of principal in the loss fields of Schedule E.  **Is this a reasoable approach?**

¹Similar investment described in [another question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/161902/unrelated-business-taxable-income).  This differs in that it’s a single mortgage instead of a fund of several.
²Plural since we file jointly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this and the previous questions you're describing a partnership.

When a partner dies, the partnership year with regards to that partner needs to close. I.e.: the partnership cuts all the books as if the year ended with regard to that partner, and then the successor partner (your wife, in this case) becomes the partner of record for the remainder of the year.

What it means is that the *partnership* needs to calculate the K-1 for your MIL as of the date of death, and then *another* K-1 for your wife for the remainder period. They have to do it, you need to explain to them that it's their legal obligation. Read the write-up [here](https://www.thetaxadviser.com/issues/2015/aug/accounting-for-death-of-partner.html).

As to the reporting, your wife would have probably inherited your MIL's share as is as of the date of her passing, including the invested basis since it hasn't been written off at that time. As such, the $5000 loss of principal should be attributable to your wife, and as such your approach sounds reasonable. You do need to get the partnership issue the K-1s accordingly for 2022 for both of them, and for your wife for 2023.

You would probably want to consult a licensed tax advisor and/or attorney.

Comment: I already asked them for the K-1 and they said they already sent a 1099.  I asked for that but didn't get it.  I assume the lack of 2022 K-1 to us is due to the mortgagee making NO payments that year.  IF there was a K-1 for the MIL, it would have gone to the trustee for her estate.  Over the past several years, I have frequently not received some of my 1099s and W-2s.  IRS has so far never protested the amounts I entered based on my own accounting records.

Answer (score 0):

The legal structure of the fund could be relevant. If it is informal, it would be taxed as a partnership loss.

Schedule E sounds correct for this scenario; also take a look at Form 8582 regarding passive activity losses.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at 8582 for the loss next year.